# Check permissions for serialized child objects using Guardian

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-guardian

I have three models where one Document has many Blocks and one Block has many Comments.

```py
class Document(models.Model):
  name = models.Charfield()

class Block(models.Model):
  document = models.ForeignKey(to=Document)

class Comment
  block = models.ForgeinKey(to=Block)
```

Users can have permissions for `Document` which allows them to see all `Block`s in it. Users can also add `Comment`s to any Block which they can share if other users. I use [django-guardian](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to manage object-based permissions.

I have created a [`RetrieveAPIView`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrievemodelmixin) using Django Rest Framework to make the Document available.

```py
class DocumentDetailView(PermissionRequiredMixin, RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = DocumentSerializer
    permission_required = "document.view_document"
```

To include all blocks and their comments in that view, I use the following serializers (omitted `class Meta` for brevity):

```py
class DocumentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    blocks = BlockSerializer(many=True, source="block_set")

class BlockSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    comments = serializers.CommentSerializer(many=True, source="comment_set")

class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
```

I would like to restrict the comments included in `DocumentDetailView` to those to which a user has permissions. Following the logic of django-guardian I would use [`get_objects_for_users()`](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/guardian.shortcuts.html#get-objects-for-user), to filter down the QuerySet of `Block.comment_set.all()`. Yet, I don't know where to do this.

I guess to restrict the comments to those available to `request.user`, the permission-based filtering should be done in the `DocumentDetailView`, but I don't see how to do this in `get_object()`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about `django-guardian` but I guess you could override the `get_queryset` method:

```
class DocumentDetailView(PermissionRequiredMixin, RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = DocumentSerializer
    permission_required = "document.view_document"

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.check_permissions():
            queryset = super().get_queryset()
            return queryset.filter(...)  # <- here you permission filter
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe I am mistaken, but I don't think `RetrieveAPIView` even implements `get_queryset()`? Also, using `queryset.filter()` doesn't work well for checking permissions with django-guardian.

Comment: `RetrieveAPIView` has get_queryset method for sure as it extend `GenericAPIView`.  For filter arguments I don't know the data model of django-gardian, how is it related to User model ?

Comment: Did you find a solution ? If not I have a few hours to dig into it as I'm curious about django-guardian.

Comment: Not yet. I had a look at [django-rest-framework-guardian](https://github.com/rpkilby/) but I don't think it offers a solution. There's also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36553197/permission-checks-in-drf-viewsets-are-not-working-right) which is close but not quite my problem. Maybe it'd be best to split up the view and put comments in a different endpoint.